# Powershell Sessions: Best Practices

Tags: powershell

When using Powershell PSSessions, I've experienced issues when trying to do "too much" inside a single session. In particular, I've had issues deleting files that were previously copied within the same session. In general, I've taken the approach of breaking my remote operations into finite steps and opening/closing a separate session for each step.

I'm curious if there are any known issues with using long running sessions. And if there are best practices for how much work should be done within a single session.

My impression is that a session is a lightweight process and should be used for doing relatively few operations.

Any related information is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a best practice for sessions.  I often keep sessions open all day when running monitors.  It's wise generally to keep any scripts/operations to a one thing - one operation type dynamic.  So I wouldn't use the same session for a bunch of unrelated tasks unless it's interactive.

The other thing to think about is do you have a reason to persist a session?  I only do it on occasion and usually just do ad hoc sessions as needed.